# cudnnGetConvolutionBackwardDataWorkspaceSize returned negative value

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I am using TensorFlow v1.4.1 along with a Tesla P100 GPU on Linux. When I try to train my network, I receive this error:
`tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3111] cudnnGetConvolutionBackwardDataWorkspaceSize() returned negative sizeInBytes value. This could be a cudnn bug.`

I am not sure what the this Warning means. I also see that, after restoring from the checkpoint, the loss is not the same as what it was before saving the checkpoint.

Any pointer would be helpful. I tried to look through the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc), which wasn't very clear to me.

Comment: the best thing to do would probably be to file a bug with a complete test case at developer.nvidia.com

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know a solution, but I found the same issue. This seems to happen when my network is larger. Perhaps it is related to memory issue.